# Relative positioning of nodes as labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I am using nodes as labels on a graph, and I'm having issues with them overlapping. I know I could move them manually, but this will be part of a larger document that will generate this same graph for a number of metrics, and the labels could have a different relative placement to each other for each one. Is there a way to write this so that it shifts the label nodes as needed for each graph? I would prefer they move left/right rather than up/down, as a space consideration.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} %NEW
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{RYGgreen}{RGB}{143,185,53}
\definecolor{RYGyellow}{RGB}{230,226,46}
\definecolor{RYGred}{RGB}{230,71,71}

% goals
\newcommand\NormalGoal{0.9}
\newcommand\NormalGoalWarning{0.91}
\newcommand\CurrentMeasureValue{0.7127625}
\newcommand\PreviousMeasureValue{0.653847}

%%% PercentWithDecimal %%%
% turns a value into a percent with the specified number of digits after the decimal point
% input 1 - the number to be rounded
% input 2 - the number of digits after the decimal point
\newcommand\PercentValue{}
\newcommand\PercentWithDecimal[2]{%
    \pgfmathparse{100*#1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=#2]{\pgfmathresult}{\PercentValue}%
    \PercentValue\%%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}{h}% normal goal
            % draw line
            \draw[line width=5pt, RYGred](0,0) -- (14,0); % not meeting goal
            \draw[line width=5pt, RYGyellow](14*\NormalGoal,0) -- (14,0); % warning zone
            \draw[line width=5pt, RYGgreen](14*\NormalGoalWarning,0) -- (14,0); % meeting goal
            \node[left] at (0,0) {0\%}; % label
            \node[right] at (14,0) {100\%}; % label
            % draw goal marker
            \draw[draw=black, line width=2pt] (14*\NormalGoal,-0.5)% goal line
            node[below] at (14*\NormalGoal,-0.5){90\%}% 
            node[above] at (14*\NormalGoal,0.5){goal}% 
            --  (14*\NormalGoal,0.5); % 
            % current value line
            \draw[draw=RYGred, line width=2pt] (14*\CurrentMeasureValue, -0.5)
            node[below] at (14*\CurrentMeasureValue, -0.5){\PercentWithDecimal{\CurrentMeasureValue}{2}}%
            node[above] at (14*\CurrentMeasureValue, 0.5){current}%
            -- (14*\CurrentMeasureValue,0.5); % 
            % previous measurement period value line
            \draw[draw=gray, line width=2pt] (14*\PreviousMeasureValue, -0.5)
            node[below] at (14*\PreviousMeasureValue, -0.5){\PercentWithDecimal{\PreviousMeasureValue}{2}}%
            node[above] at (14*\PreviousMeasureValue, 0.5){previous}%
            -- (14*\PreviousMeasureValue,0.5); % 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}    
\end{document}
```

And the output of this is:

[image: graph output from the above code]

Comment: Just to make sure, I understand correctly: the labels should shift to the left or to the right, only if there is too little space? Or would it also be okay to align certain labels always to the left or to the right, regardless of their actual position?

Comment: @JasperHabicht The former - the labels should shift left or right only if there is too little space.

Answer (score 1):

- Is it possible that the percentages are equal or very close?
  I suggest a rotation of 30°
- For vertical alignment in nodes \vphantom{bp}

  ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
   %\usepackage{etoolbox} %NEW
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \definecolor{RYGgreen}{RGB}{143,185,53}
   \definecolor{RYGyellow}{RGB}{230,226,46}
   \definecolor{RYGred}{RGB}{230,71,71}

   % goals
   \newcommand\NormalGoal{0.9}
   \newcommand\NormalGoalWarning{0.91}
   \newcommand\CurrentMeasureValue{0.7127625}
   \newcommand\PreviousMeasureValue{0.653847}


   %%% PercentWithDecimal %%%
   % turns a value into a percent with the specified number of digits after the decimal point
   % input 1 - the number to be rounded
   % input 2 - the number of digits after the decimal point
   \newcommand\PercentValue{}
   \newcommand\PercentWithDecimal[2]{%
       \pgfmathparse{100*#1}%
       \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=#2]{\pgfmathresult}{\PercentValue}%
       \PercentValue\%%
   }

   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
       \begin{tikzpicture}{h}% normal goal
           % draw line
           \draw[line width=5pt, RYGred](0,0) -- (14,0); % not meeting goal
           \draw[line width=5pt, RYGyellow](14*\NormalGoal,0) -- (14,0); % warning zone
           \draw[line width=5pt, RYGgreen](14*\NormalGoalWarning,0) -- (14,0); % meeting goal
           \node[left] at (0,0) {0\%}; % label
           \node[right] at (14,0) {100\%}; % label
           % draw goal marker            
           \draw[draw=black, line width=2pt] (14*\NormalGoal,-0.5)% goal line
           node[rotate=30,below] at (14*\NormalGoal,-0.5){90\%}% 
           node[rotate=30,above] at (14*\NormalGoal,0.5){\vphantom{bp}goal}% 
           --  (14*\NormalGoal,0.5); % 
           % current value line
           \draw[draw=RYGred, line width=2pt] (14*\CurrentMeasureValue, -0.5)
           node[rotate=30,below] at (14*\CurrentMeasureValue, -0.5){\PercentWithDecimal{\CurrentMeasureValue}{2}}%
           node[rotate=30,above] at (14*\CurrentMeasureValue, 0.5){\vphantom{bp}current}%
           -- (14*\CurrentMeasureValue,0.5); % 
           % previous measurement period value line
           \draw[draw=gray, line width=2pt] (14*\PreviousMeasureValue, -0.5)
           node[rotate=30,below] at (14*\PreviousMeasureValue, -0.5){\PercentWithDecimal{\PreviousMeasureValue}{2}}%
           node[rotate=30,above] at (14*\PreviousMeasureValue, 0.5){\vphantom{bp}previous}%
           -- (14*\PreviousMeasureValue,0.5); % 
       \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: While I really like the look of this, it's entirely possible that the numbers will be so close that even this would overlap. But I'll keep this in mind for other visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

You already positioned text manually. So, I would just add "left" or "right" option where needed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{RYGgreen}{RGB}{143,185,53}
\definecolor{RYGyellow}{RGB}{230,226,46}
\definecolor{RYGred}{RGB}{230,71,71}

% goals
\newcommand\NormalGoal{0.9}
\newcommand\NormalGoalWarning{0.91}
\newcommand\CurrentMeasureValue{0.7127625}
\newcommand\PreviousMeasureValue{0.653847}

\newcommand\PercentValue{}
\newcommand\PercentWithDecimal[2]{%
    \pgfmathparse{100*#1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=#2]{\pgfmathresult}{\PercentValue}%
    \PercentValue\%%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
  arr/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw=#2, line width=#1}, 
every node/.style = {text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex, 
                     inner xsep=0pt, text=black}% normal goal
                           ]
            % draw line
\draw[arr=5pt/RYGred] (0,0) node[left] {0\%}-- (14,0); % not meeting goal
\draw[arr=5pt/RYGyellow](14*\NormalGoal,0) -- (14,0); % warning zone
\draw[arr=5pt/RYGgreen](14*\NormalGoalWarning,0) -- (14,0) node[right] {100\%}; % meeting
            % draw goal marker
\draw[arr=2pt/black]   
    (14*\NormalGoal,-0.5) node[below] {90\%} --  
    (14*\NormalGoal,0.5)  node[above] {goal};
            % current value line
\draw[arr=2pt/RYGred] 
    (14*\CurrentMeasureValue, -0.5) node[below right] {\PercentWithDecimal{\CurrentMeasureValue}{2}} -- 
    (14*\CurrentMeasureValue,0.5)   node[above right] {current}; %
            % previous measurement period value line
\draw[arr=2pt/gray] 
    (14*\PreviousMeasureValue, -0.5) node[below left] {\PercentWithDecimal{\PreviousMeasureValue}{2}} --
    (14*\PreviousMeasureValue,0.5)   node[above left] {previous}; %
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I also take liberty and define styles for lines and nodes, which enable to write shorter image code.

Comment: I think this might be my best option. I'll have to add a little bit to check what order the values are in, but that'll be easy. I appreciate the bit about defining styles for lines and nodes, I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so I'm happy for any tips and tricks like this!

Comment: @kgrafton, any news? If answer solve your problem, it may be a time to consider to accepting it ;-)